# How to estimate 7-Zip time to compress and email two PPTs 700KB each? Windows 10 Enterprise network folder

Tags: windows-10, 7-zip, filesystem-corruption

I need help to know if 7-Zip is freezing or still working.
My interpretation of following status from 7-Zip is it is frozen.
However, since these files are in network folder, I am not too eager to end this task in Task Manager.

> Remaining Time 00:00:00 Total Size 1358 KB Speed 3727B/s Processed
> 1358 KB Compressed Size 580 KB Compressed Ration 42%

What is I end this task? any risk of causing corrupting network folder for Windows 10 Enterprise?

Comment: email dialogue box is hidden misled me to post this; 7-Zip created the email but did not bring its dialogue box to the front. How to fix dialogue box not in the front? I nearly made a mistake to end this 7-Zip task if I did not spent time investigating. 20 minutes lost...

Comment: 700KB is nothing.  It's not even really worth zipping, unless you're trying to encrypt or otherwise protect the files.

Comment: *Any* PC that can run Win10 should complete the Zip operation in a second or two. the message "Speed 3727B/s" clearly shows on that PC it took << 1 sec.